# rotates an bitmap image by any degrees in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, bitmap

I am kind of new to Blackberry.  I have an Image that I need to rotate to certain degree depending on input from user.. I have tried searching but cant seem to find anything on it.  Can any one point me to right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

> Download the **zip** file from this link: [BitmapRotate](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Rotate-and-scale-bitmaps/ta-p/492524) at down side.
>
> Extract and take the **ImageManipulator.java** from that add to your project;
>
> and use this code from this link: [RotatingBitmap on Blackberry](http://metova.com/display/PUBTECH/Scaling+and+rotating+bitmaps+on+BlackBerry)

I think this helps you;

or

take the below BitmapRotate.zip code to for rotate an image from this link:

[Bitmap rotation in blackberry](http://alishaik001.blogspot.in/2012/08/blackberry-rotate-image-in-any-degree.html)

Comment: i use this code but remove transparency please send me another example

Comment: Check the update one; Take the zip code and run it; and then let me know.

Comment: To get the file from this link: https://www.box.com/files#/files/0/f/0/1/f_2980271171  You should have a member in this link; First signUp and then try;

Comment: your file is delete form your server send me hiresh.scs@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

There's a [J2ME Army Knife library](http://www.j2mearmyknife.com/live-demo/), check it.

It does contain rotate functionality too.

Comment: You might also check [this link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/how-to-rotate-Image-or-Graphic/m-p/232750/highlight/true#M36233) if there are troubles porting some of that J2ME army knife code to be usable with the classes in RIM's libraries (e.g. `Bitmap`)

Answer (score 1):

This is a part of KB article in Blackberry ..
Pass your bitmap & Angle to this function to get rotated bitmap.

```java
public static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap oldImage) throws Exception 
{
    int w = oldImage.getWidth();
    int h = oldImage.getHeight();
    int d = Math.max(w, h);
    int amountPxAdded = 0;
    if (w > h) {
        amountPxAdded = w - h;
    }
    Bitmap oldBitmapSquared = new Bitmap(d, d);
    int[] data = new int[w * h];
    oldImage.getARGB(data, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
    oldBitmapSquared.setARGB(data, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
    Bitmap finalRes = new Bitmap(h, w);
    int fW = finalRes.getWidth();
    int fH = finalRes.getHeight();
    oldImage = null;
    Bitmap rotated = rotateSquareImage(oldBitmapSquared, <Angle>);
    oldBitmapSquared = null;
    data = new int[fW * fH];
    rotated.getARGB(data, 0, fW, amountPxAdded, 0, fW, fH);
    rotated = null;
    finalRes.setARGB(data, 0, fW, 0, 0, fW, fH);
    return finalRes;
}

private static Bitmap rotateSquareImage(Bitmap oldB, int angle) throws Exception {
    int w = oldB.getWidth();
    int h = oldB.getHeight();
    Bitmap newB = new Bitmap(w, h);
    int[] oldD = new int[w * h];
    int[] newD = new int[w * h];
    oldB.getARGB(oldD, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
    int[][] old2d = new int[h][w];
    int[] js;
    int old2dLen = old2d.length;
    int jsLen;
    for (int i = 0; i < old2dLen; i++) {
        js = old2d[i];
        jsLen = js.length;
        for (int j = 0; j < jsLen; j++) {
            js[j] = oldD[i * w + j];
        }
    }
    int[][] rotated = new int[h][w];
    for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < w; ++j) {
            rotated[i][j] = old2d[h - j - 1][i];
        }
    }
    old2d = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < w; ++j) {
            newD[i * w + j] = rotated[i][j];
        }
    }
    rotated = null;
    newB.setARGB(newD, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
    return newB;
}
```

Comment: What problem you are facing... ?

Comment: rotate function how to send <Angle> valuse Bitmap rotated = rotateSquareImage(oldBitmapSquared, <Angle>); and how to use rotateSquareImage function i modify public static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap oldImage, int ang) and pass Bitmap rotated = rotateSquareImage(oldBitmapSquared, ang); but png bitmap not rotat

Comment: in place of <Angle> use 90 , & first simply check Are you able to rotate image to 90 or not. 
Simply use rotate(<Your bitmap object>)> 
This function will imlicitly call RotateSquare Function to 90.

Comment: i check it rotate 90 degree but i want to rotate all angle game run time

Comment: Cant you pass a integer variable in place of 90 , & change this int value according to ur business logic. It must rotate to that angle.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15839/discussion-between-hiresh-bansodkar-and-shashank-agarwal)

Comment: i am a game developer and i want to rotate bitmap png image run time your code not working game run time and i use ImageManipulator.java this class also but in this class transparency remove

Comment: What do you want to have ? a running code according to your need. You need to put a lot of efforts to do so. 
Did u tried some logic , some changes in codes to get appropriate result?